# Help to write regex using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a URL where I want to replace the equal to (=) next to &c and &app with %3d using php

```
$ddd_url = '<asset ="http://www.ggtt.com/dfghdzHV8?f=videos&c=AIfgdfdfVQQ93m-ikEn0N3FqIfgdf45tdgdsHuwtysV-I8SEdfsgdf44xmNPW_B-kX33bw&app=dde_gdata"/>';
```

I also want to remove the _8 from the $thumbnail

$thumbnail = "http://d2dsfsd.humbnails/20415/33-d148-45b1-9098-11e5c/thumbnail_8.jpg";

Comment: do you just want the '=' characters replaced, or do you want to urlencode the entire thing? I have a feeling you want the latter - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str_replace( array( '&c='   , '&app='   ), 
             array( '&c%3d' , '&app%3d' ), 
             $url
           );
```

Avoid regex when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
$result = preg_replace('/(&c|&app)(=)/i', '$1%3d', $ddd_url);
```

Comment: I also want to remove the _8 from the $thumbnail

$thumbnail = "http://d2dsfsd.humbnails/20415/33-d148-45b1-9098-11e5c/thumbnail_8.jpg";

Comment: open another question. this isn't a chat